# What xsd will let an element have itself as a sub element infinitely?

Tags: xml, xsd

How can I create an xsd to give me this type of xml structure that can go on infinitely?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<SampleXml>
    <Items>
        <Item name="SomeName" type="string">
            This would be the value
        </Item>
        <Item name="SecondName" type="string">
            This is the next string
        </Item>
        <Item name="AnotherName" type="list">
            <Items>
                <Item name="SubName" type="string">
                    A string in a sub list
                </Item>
                <Item name="SubSubName" type="list">
                    <Items>
                        <Item name="HowDoI" type="string">
                            How do I keep this going infinately?
                        </Item>
                    </Items>
                </Item>
            </Items>
        </Item>
    </Items>
</SampleXml>
```

The only solution I have found has been to just repeat in the xsd as many times as I am willing to copy.  Like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="SampleXml">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Items">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Item">
                                <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                                    <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
                                        <xs:element name="Items">
                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:sequence>
                                                    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Item">
                                                        <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                                                            <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
                                                                <xs:element name="Items">
                                                                    <xs:complexType>
                                                                        <xs:sequence>
                                                                            <xs:element name="Item">
                                                                                <xs:complexType>
                                                                                    <xs:simpleContent>
                                                                                        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                                                                            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                                                                            <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                                                                        </xs:extension>
                                                                                    </xs:simpleContent>
                                                                                </xs:complexType>
                                                                            </xs:element>
                                                                        </xs:sequence>
                                                                    </xs:complexType>
                                                                </xs:element>
                                                            </xs:sequence>
                                                            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                                            <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                                        </xs:complexType>
                                                    </xs:element>
                                                </xs:sequence>
                                            </xs:complexType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                    <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: My left eye is now my right eye! +1 for trying to get rid of that (and using xsd in the first place).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `<xs:element ref="bla" />` to recursively refer to the elements.
A simple example:

```
<xs:element name="recursive">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="recursive" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Allows you to write this:

```
<recursive>
  <recursive>
    <recursive />
  </recursive>
  <recursive />
  <recursive>
    <recursive>
      <recursive />
    </recursive>
  </recursive>
</recursive>
```

Usage of the 'ref' attribute also helps greatly in increasing the readability of your XSD. This is how I would write yours:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="SampleXml">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="Items" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="Items">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="Item" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="Item">
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="Items" minOccurs="0" />
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
      <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Note how use of 'ref' even when it's not strictly necessary (such as when SampleXml refers to Items) makes the XSD less of a nested mess and more readable.

Comment: is it the same though to declare all elements at the top-level compared to nesting them semantically? That is, I'd expect nesting to mean that Item only has meaning when existing inside Items and not standalone in some XML document

Comment: @GeorgeBirbilis  Yeah, I would agree with that. There's probably cases where it's important to make use of this distinction, but where it isn't I think there's not much harm in being somewhat less technically correct in favor of a huge gain in readability.

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this, using the `ref` attribute:

```
<xs:element name="Items">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element ref="Item" />
    </xs:sequence> 
  </xd:complexType
 </xd:element>

<xs:element name="Item">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="Items" />
    </xs:sequence> 
  </xd:complexType
 </xd:element>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using the `ref` attribute:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Items">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Item">
                    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                        <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
                            <xs:element ref="Items" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                        <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="SampleXml">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Items" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```